# Calculate time difference between two checkins in Foursquare

Tags: foursquare

I'm working on an app that would calculate the time taken between two checkins (Say the time taken from Home to Office).

Is there a way to do that with the Foursquare API?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely! You have some options:

- Using our [real-time API](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/realtime) so we'll send a push to your servers each time one of your users checks in
- Use the [users/checkins](https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/users/checkins) endpoint to retrieve a list of check-ins for a particular user

Both will require you to [authenticate](https://developer.foursquare.com/overview/auth) users first.